# Equivalent sensorLandscape screenOrientation for api level 7

Tags: android, landscape, screen-orientation

I have an activity that requests a landscape mode.
However with some tablets, the reverseLandscape should be used.

That's why I'd like to use the sensorLandscape screen orientation, but it is only available for API 9+.

Mine is level 7, and if I change it I will loose a big part of users. 
How is it possible to do this feature with API level 7 please ?

Thanks...